# Inspect parse.com request object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I would like to be able to print out what the request object when using parse.com cloud code. For example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("createRelationship", function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

console.log("request: ");
console.log(request);
```

However, I don't see any output for `console.log(request)`. I know the request is not empty.

How can I get a "javascript" object or a parse object "to_string" and have it print out to the log files. This is for debugging purposes.

Thanks,

Comment: Where did you inspect the log?

Comment: Inspect it at the main.js in both the terminal and parse logs

Comment: Inspect the terminal by running parse develop app

Comment: Okay, just want to make sure you inspect it via parse log. Maybe try `console.log(JSON.stringify(request))`.

Comment: Seems to work. Thanks. Can you make this into an official answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `JSON.stringify` the `request` object or return it as response to inspect its content.

Sample code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('ShowRequest', function(request, response) {
  console.log(request);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(request));
  return response.success(request);
});
```

Comment: If you add a label along with it won't work. Eg.  `console.log("request", JSON.stringify(request));` which is weird...

Comment: Arjun U. - change your comma to a plus sign and it will. console.log("request: " + JSON.stringify(request));